# In ZIO what’s the difference between flatMap and zipRight?

Tags: scala, zio

Looking at their signatures, these seem very similar.  What’s the semantic difference between these two functions in ZIO?

Answer (score 8):

Their signatures are not really similar at all, and just looking at them should be enough to determine their difference.

```scala
// I am going to omit all the extra noise of ZIO.
// Since this is just a general question of the "Program as Values" paradigm,
// which is the underlying paradigm behind these libraries.
trait IO[+A] {
  def zipRight[B](iob: IO[B]): IO[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => IO[B]): IO[B]
}
```

The purpose of `zipRight` *(which could be better called `andThen`)* is to compose two independent programs together, where the resulting program represents running the first *(left)* one and then the second *(right)* one, preserving the result of the later; while ignoring the result of the former.

Whereas, `flatMap` allows to compose two programs, but where the second one depends on the result of the first one. Such dependency is the key point.
We can see that in the signature: `A => IO[B]`, meaning we can decide what to do based on the result.

Thus, `zipRight` serves for scenarios like:

> Write a log message AND THEN send a notification.

Rather, `flatMap` being more powerful allow us to do something like:

> Read a message from a queue and IF the value is priority THEN process it right away, OTHERWISE write it to a table.

---

PS: Note that `zipRight` can easily be implemented using `flatMap`

```scala
def zipRight[B](iob: IO[B]): IO[B] =
  this.flatMap(_ => iob) // Note how we ignore the result of evaluating this.
```

But the opposite is impossible.